# Adding dynamic views in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to add a dynamic view for my fragment.

I am using this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Button myButton = new Button(Builtprofile.context);
    myButton.setText("Press me");
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

      RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(Builtprofile.context);
      myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
      buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

      myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.q1, container, false);

// I want to add myLayout in place of R.layout.q1

    return rootView;

}
```

Comment: What you want exactly?Is there any error??

Comment: yes actually, i want to replace R.layout.q1 with myLayout

Comment: have an empty xml layout file with just the Layout as the parent. Use the `inflater.inflate(R....)` to inflate your view. then append your custom layout to `rootView`. Ex: `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.q1, container, false);` then do `rootView.addView(myLayout);`. Play around with the concept and see if that works. Or you can get a reference to the layout with `findViewById` in your rootview and append your custom layout that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    Button myButton = new Button(Builtprofile.context);
    myButton.setText("Press me");
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.q1, container, false);

    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);

    return rootView;
}
```

Have an empty xml layout with just a RelativeLayout called "mainLayout"(or what ever you want to call it). That way you can append any dynamically generated controls

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.xml, null);

container.addView(v);
```