# Create UI elements dynamically in a fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments, android-view

I wanted to create UI elements in a fragment dynamically. I have tried various of examples but it didn't work.

How can I create a button for example?

Comment: There are tons of ways to achieve it and it's not the place to ask for it here. Start by reading the android developer guides or any off site guide.

Comment: Yeah I know and what I said before I already did it but it didn't work...

Comment: You can try this.I've used it before, it works.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785265/adding-dynamic-views-in-a-fragment

Comment: Please add the code that "didn't work" to your questions instead of having us guess what you tried.

Comment: "I have tried various of examples but it didn't work." What exactly did you try? What about them didn't work? Did you get any compiler errors?